# Data structure to store IP ranges, allowing quick search for given IP (Java)

Tags: search, data-structures, ip, range, cidr

I'm trying to think of an efficient data structure to represent IP ranges, as described just below. I know what I want to try is fairly easily possible, I just can't seem to put my finger on it.

So, let's say I have hundreds of separate IP ranges in the format 1.1.1.0 - 1.1.2.255, or whatever (but not CIDR format like 1.1.1.0/24).

The different ranges are not consecutive, so there could be millions of IPs apart between the end of one and the start of the next. They could/would instead be represented in integer format if preferred (i.e., 16843008 - 16843519 in this example).

There would be no known overlapping of IP addresses into other ranges.

Basically, these ranges represent ASN netblocks, if you're curious. And I need to make a tool to determine if any given IP fits into one of these ranges -- but the tool must be fairly fast (less than .5 second, ideally).

Now, if I have hundreds or thousands of these ranges, which cover millions of IPs, and want to find if a given IP is in one of the ranges (or not), what would be the fastest way, while also not being too memory intensive?

There are a few options I can think of:

- Build up a HashSet which contains every single IP from all of the ranges, and just do a contains(ip) against that. I'd expect about 50 million IPs in there. Fast, but seems a bit wasteful, memory wise?
- Have a TreeMap whose key is the starting IP of each range and whose value is the end IP. Traverse the tree and check for each key if the test IP is larger than that key, but smaller than the next key. If it is, then investigate the value (i.e., end IP of range) and if the IP is smaller than the map's value, then the IP is in the range -- if not, there's no point continuing and can assume the IP is not in any of the ranges. Could probably binary search through the tree's keys to get to a conclusion quicker, rather than check in order?
- Another idea is to have a HashMap who's keys would be all the possible subnets within all the ranges (I realise there would be many), for example "123.123.123, 123.123.124, 123.123.125, 211.211.211, 211.211.215", etc... Then if I'm asked to check IP 123.123.124.144, I could see if its subnet (123.123.124) is a key in the map firstly. The value of the map might be a custom object containing the start and end IP of the range associated with that particular subnet. Then you could just use that to check if the full IP fits in the range. This special object would be shared with many entries in the map, as obviously there could be many subnets in a given range.

So, any thoughts / ideas / opinions? I have a feeling my second idea there might be a good way to go? Thanks for the info...quite excited to hear your ideas!

Comment: The more I thought about this, I realised the problem was pretty easy to solve for me. Simply keep a massive HashMap where the keys are every possible subnet from each range. That has a max size of 1764705, but for me it'll only ever be bout 5% of that -- so it's not too big. I had forgotten that each IP in a subnet could all be treated the same, as ASNs cannot be broken down any smaller than at the subnet level.

Answer (score 3):

If ranges don't contain subranges, you may check guava RangeSet.
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#RangeSet
In fact, I haven't analysed the time and space complexity of RangeSet, but RangeSet seems to satisfy your requirement quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I use an AVL tree, with the IP range as the node value and a suitable comparison function.  (Where the range is a..b (a <= b), when comparing two ranges r1 and r2: r1 < r2 if r1.b < r2.a ; r1 "==" r2 if r1.a >= r2.a and r1.b <= r2.b ; r1 > r2 if r1.a > r2.b.  So "==" means r1 is equal to or included in r2.)

If you have no overlaps, that is sufficient.  If you have overlaps (as I do, but I'm handling network prefixes) you end up with AVL trees nested inside AVL trees.

When you say no ASN net-blocks overlap, I assume that if an ASN has a /yy delegated to it, you are breaking the parent /xx into separate, but contiguous, net-blocks.

Since your list of net-blocks doesn't change that often, you probably don't need an AVL tree.  You could just sort the netblocks and hit the list with a binary chop.  If you need something that gets going faster than a binary tree/chop you could have an auxilary set of pointers into a binary chop, using the ms-byte of the start of the range being looked up to identify the first and last ranges worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure I use. Let's have another table, the table `locations` in this case just to see the purpose and use of IP ranges in a real situation.

```
--
-- Table structure for table `locations`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations` (
  `location_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`location_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
);

--
-- Table structure for table `locations_to_ip_ranges`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locations_to_ip_ranges` (
  `l_ip_r` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `starting_ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ending_ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `starting_cidr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ending_cidr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`l_ip_r`),
  KEY `location_id` (`location_id`)
);
```

Here are a few records from the second table

```
l_ip_r  location_id starting_ip     ending_ip        starting_cidr  ending_cidr
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
94005   47          217.147.0.0     217.147.15.255   3650289664     3650293759
94004   47          217.146.32.0    217.146.47.255   3650232320     3650236415
94003   47          217.145.144.0   217.145.159.255  3650195456     3650199551
94002   47          217.145.16.0    217.145.31.255   3650162688     3650166783
94001   47          217.144.176.0   217.144.191.255  3650138112     3650142207
```

The following is an useful function to convert an IP address to CIDR number. It is written in PHP but I believe it would be easy to convert it to Java. `explode()` function used here splits a string according to a given separator.

```
function ip_address_to_cidr($ip_address){
    $ips = explode(".", $ip_address);
    return ($ips[3] + $ips[2] * 256 + $ips[1] * 65536 + $ips[0] * 16777216);
}
```

So, if you want to get the country for a given IP address you will have something like this

```
// call the ip_ip_address_to_cidr function passing the remote_address as an argument
$cidr = ip_address_to_cidr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

// pass the returned $cidr to the following query and get the location_id
$set = mysql_query("
    SELECT location_id 
    FROM locations_to_ip_ranges
    WHERE " . $cidr . " BETWEEN starting_cidr AND ending_cidr
");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($set);
echo $row->location_id
```

Since I need multi-language support, there's another table `locations_to_languages` which I left out in order to keep this plain and simple. Currently these tables contain tens of millions of data and I have no performance issue.

Side note: I haven't use Java for a long time so the snippet above is in PHP, but I believe it wouldn't be hard to understand the logic and convert it to Java if needed.

Comment: Hi, sure it could very easily done at a database level but that is far too slow and it traverses through way too much data. I am looking for a suitable data structure, for in-memory searching, without traversing through everything. I'm not looking for a database schema. Thanks for the detailed answer however!

Answer (score 0):

We can use btrees via which we can map the ip address in primary memory and then map them to secondary memory.
As we know we need to store fairly large number of ip address we can't store them in primary memory as it is so,better if we would use a btree.
As it's similar to hashing principle also effective memory utilization.